# chromium aw snap refresh

Tags: python, chromium

I have headless linux with opened chromium in kiosk mode. From time to time I am getting "Aw, snap" error (no idea why, but for now it is not important). What I am trying to do is to automatically refresh page when "Aw, snap" error occurs. Any idea, how?

Comment: Using extension or by modifying source code of Chromium?

Comment: same question asked here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/KYzTOma4pGQ
I'd be happy to see a linux answer for this, where I can add such an extension via CLI.