# What can be the cause of the "Aw, Snap!" error in a chromium browser in KIOSK mode(Raspberry PI)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspberry-os

I made a Chromium Kiosk on Rasberry Pi following this guide:

https://reelyactive.github.io/diy/pi-kiosk/

I run an Angular application on it(people can log in to start their shift), but sometimes, when I walk past it, it displays the "Aw, Snap!" error.

**What can cause this error?**

**How to make the Chromium Kiosk reload automatically, when this error occours?**

I looked at this post:
[chromium aw snap refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544167/chromium-aw-snap-refresh)

But couldnt work out a solution of it.

Comment: The renderer process crashed. So there could be so many reasons behind this issue. Logging might be helpful to find the cause but it won't be always helpful. The other thing you can do is debug the crash dump file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These I found useful:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snapper-aw-snap-tab-reloa/jehgbfogcmbekbbcadldojojckehlkbi

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oh-no-you-didnt/acdablfhjbhkjbcifldncdkmlophfgda

**But!** The main problem was a memory leak.